# GNU Octave: `sh: vim: command not found`

Tags: vim, flatpak, octave

I am  running GNU Octave from `flatpak` and I have an issue with the `edit` command. In Octave's CLI when I run

```
edit file.m
```

I got the following issue:

```
sh: vim: command not found
```

I have the following set in my `octaverc` configuration file (from [GNU Octave Wiki: vim](https://wiki.octave.org/Vim)):

```
EDITOR('vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')
```

`vim` is installed on my system. I don't have any error if I replace `vim` by `nano` in the previous command.

I wonder if the problem isn't that I'm using `flatpak`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatpak app can run only executables provided by it and its runtime (org.kde.Sdk/x86_64/5.14 in case of org.octave.Octave). Nano is available in org.kde.Sdk. Neither Vim nor Emacs are available there.

You can run host program from Flatpak container using `flatpak-spawn --host`. See [How to allow GUI application in flatpak to run CLI tool?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412869).

I run Octave in terminal and after some trial-and-error I've found working configuration:

```
edit mode sync
edit home .
EDITOR('flatpak-spawn --host --env=TERM=linux /usr/bin/vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')
```

Comment: This totally makes sense but not working on my system. I got the following error: `Can't find bus: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=83dc97dce7a847508eaa5ac387352f59 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have vim installed?

If not try `sudo apt install vim -y` (for Debian/Ubuntu etc.)

Comment: Yes  `vim` is installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably that the PATH is not set or doesn't include the path in which vim is installed in.

You should open a terminal and type `which vim`, and you should have a path like `/usr/bin/vim` or something similar depending on your distribution.

And instead of just adding vim, you should have `EDITOR('/usr/bin/vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')`

Comment: Not it's not working. If it was a `PATH` issue, `nano` wouldn't work either.

Comment: It depends nano might not be in the same path, I don't know how your tools are installed nor where they are. `vim: command not found` looks really much like a PATH error to me

Comment: `vm` and `nano` are both in the same directory `/usr/bin`. Both have been installed by my package manager. `EDITOR('/usr/bin/vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')` don't work while `EDITOR('/usr/bin/nano > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')` works.